# Derivative of the map $f:S^1\to S^1: z\mapsto z^n$ is orientation preserving or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Given $f:S^1\to S^1: z\mapsto z^n$. I'm trying to show that $Df_p$ is orientation preserving: Let's try to show it at $p= (1,0)$. Tangent space at p is one dimensional and is spanned by basis vector $\partial/\partial y$. I assume $S^1$ to be oriented anticlockwise.

I want to show that $Df_p (\partial/\partial y)$ is a positive multiple of $\partial/\partial y$.

Take any $C^\infty(p)$ function $g$. Then

$Df_p(\partial/\partial y) g=\partial/\partial y|_p(g\circ f)=\partial/\partial\theta|_{\phi(p)}(g\circ f\circ \phi^{-1})$

How to go from here?

Comment: Is $n$ assumed to be positive?

Comment: Why don’t you just compute in the obvious chart on the circle?

Comment: @MoisheKohan not necessarily, but suppose so then how to go from the last equation in my post?

Comment: @TedShifrin I did that but only because I was given lot of hints to do it the charts way. My first instinct to solve OP was as I did in my post. By charts method I mean I found a chart $\phi$ such that the map $\phi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1}$ is multiplication by n. So its determinant is n which is same as the determinant of f by Chain rule.

Comment: You get one answer for positive $n$ and the opposite answer for negative $n$.

Comment: Correct, Koro. ……..